# Pagination doesnt show numbers

Tags: pagination

**Edit:**

full code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <!-- section -->

    <!-- Home Design Inner Pages -->
    <div class="ulockd-inner-home" <?php

    if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
        if ( $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg' ) )
            printf( ' style="background-image: url(%s);"', esc_url($image_src[0]) );
    }

    ?>>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="inner-conraimer-details">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1 class="text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?><</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Home Design Inner Pages -->
    <div class="ulockd-inner-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="ulockd-icd-layer">
                        <ul class="list-inline ulockd-icd-sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#"> HOME </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> > </a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#"> <?php get_breadcrumb(); ?> </a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#"> HOME </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Our Department -->
    <section class="ulockd-fservice bgc-snowshade">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
                    <div class="ulockd-main-title">
                        <h2 class="mt-separator">Our Services</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">




                <?php

                /**
                 * Setup query to show the ‘services’ post type with ‘8’ posts.
                 * Output the title with an excerpt.
                 */
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'services',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                );

                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                if (have_posts()): while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    ?>
                    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="ficon-box hvr-shadow">
                            <div class="ficon">
                                <span class="flaticon-blood-analysis text-thm2" title="Feature Icon Box"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fib-details">
                                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <p><?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?></p>
                                <a href="page-service-details">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile;


                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
                    ) );

                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <article>
                        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
                    </article>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div></div></section>
    <?php get_footer(); ?></main>
```

---

My code doesnt show numbers in custom post type archieve page.Also I tried many pagination code ( all of similar ) and they didnt work for in any page.

So, what's the problem? How can I show numbers? There is only a few post, so I want to show 1(one) character if there is no enough post to show other numbers.Also, no, I dont want write 1 as a html :)

after query:

```
<?php endwhile;


                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
                    ) ); 

                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    ?>
                <?php else: ?>
```

Comment: Can you please share your entire code here so I can help you.

Comment: @TanmayPatel I added full code

Answer (score 1):

> Change your code like this and check it.

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
```